# Is there an error in this song's subtitles or I'm not understanding it correctly?

Tags: song-lyrics, hiragana

[Here is the song.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CZQ1d1SFVX0)
My confusion comes in first seconds of this song (also repeated in the end):

ずつと ずつと (Zutzuto Zutzuto) → "one by one" (?)
or
ずっと ずっと (Zutto Zutto) → "forever forever"

So, this is what subtitle lyrics display... つ in the middle seems big one, rather than small one so first variant seems to be correct, but maybe it's just font being ambiguous like this and its actually small っ. But if you listen to what is actually sung, its totally different, something like:

つめた つめた (Tsumeta Tsumeta) → may be this 冷た "cold", maybe you know more meanings that better fit context?

So is there really this huge error in subs (and not only subs, but on all lyrics sites in the Internet I could find)? Or am I just hallucinating? My theory is – maybe they changed lyrics in the last moment before recording song, and didn't had time to change lyrics texts, so they left it as it is?

Answer (score 3):

You're both misreading and mishearing it. The singer sings it as three syllables rather than than two, but it's still basically 'Zu-u-tto'. Additionally, it's definitely a small っ - just compare the size of it to the large つ in ついていこう two lines later.

ず (and all other ザ行 kana) are often pronounced with [dz] rather than simple [z], so perhaps that's the root of your mishearing.

[image: Here is the ずっと ずっと line]

[image: And here is the ついていこうって part.]

As you can see, the っ in the ずっと is smaller than the beginning part of ついていこうって, and the same size as the っ in って. Additionally, ずつとずつと makes no sense, because ずつ is always paired with a number word and not used on its own.

Additionally, compare the sound of the と in the first line to the た in ドキドキした in the next line. They sound clearly different. The American English 'long O' is a diphthong [ou] - like a Spanish or Japanese short O followed by an 'oo' sound in the same syllable, but the Japanese O is, as I have just said, just the first part of that sound.

And there's definitely no め sound at all there. If every single source on the internet, including those transcribed by Japanese people, say one thing, and you hear another, you should probably accept that you're the one who's hearing it wrong.

Comment: Seriously? That is small つ? I compared it in image editor and the difference between them is literally 1-2 pixels. This is ridiculous font if you are to be correct. Compare that to StackExchange font. つっ
No its definately not zuuuto. Because there is clear me in the middle and TA in the end. If it's really small TSU, than this word can't contain ME in the middle no matter what, but there it is. IDK what's wrong with other people's hearing and how they didn't notice this before, something's clearly up with this song. I don't want to scan this sound to prove anything to you, just listen better.

Comment: @ScienceDiscoverer Why ask the question if the only possibility you were open to was confirmation of what you already thought?